# C# Processes in a Listview?

Tags: c#, listview, process

I want to list all running processes in a Listview.  I wrote codes below but I'm getting error that "***Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attemp to continue.  If you click Quit, the application will close immediately. Process must exit before requested information can be determined***".   I am a beginner user in C#.  Thank you.`

**-----The problem was solved by Ricky's message-----**
.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void btnGetProcesses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
             ListViewItem lstViewItems = new ListViewItem();

             foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                lstViewItems.Text=process.Id.ToString();
                lstViewItems.SubItems.Add(process.ProcessName);
                lstViewItems.SubItems.Add(process.StartTime.ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(lstViewItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you complete that error message, the situation will be clearer

Comment: Post a **complete** error message, not first sentence. Look into `InnerException` for more details if you need. Observe call stack to see at **which line** error occurs. Perhaps learning [how to debug](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/) will help for any further case.

Comment: Hi and very welcome to SO. Please post the entire stacktrace for the exception you receive.

Comment: All of you are right . The message was too long to write. The problem was solwed by Ricky. Thank you.

Comment: Steve2, I understand what you mean.  I rewrote the error message completely and read "How does accepting an answer work?".  Sorry I am late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will work. In your code, you are trying to add the new item at the same location.

```
void btnGetProcesses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    ListViewItem lstViewItems = null;
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        lstViewItems = new ListViewItem();
        lstViewItems.Text=process.Id.ToString();
        lstViewItems.SubItems.Add(process.ProcessName);
        lstViewItems.SubItems.Add(process.StartTime.ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lstViewItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Artal Then you should select Ricky's post as the correct answer.